# Does MEMO mean memory?

Tags: american-english

Jezz.. How did I miss the **memo** of Brooklyn?

Does MEMO mean memory ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your favorite dictionary can help here...

Comment: But the use of ***of*** is suspect.  It probably ought to be ***on***.  Memos or memorandums are written *on* a topic.  Or they are *from* a person or office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Memo" is short for "memorandum". A memorandum is often a small note, verbal or written, telling someone to remember something.

Answer (score 1):

***Memorandum*** is the most common meaning of "[memo](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/MEMO)." See link for others.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.